# How to change formio form select component value in angular

Tags: angular, formio

I have one submit from in formio which contains city dropdown and other fields.
And I need to set value to city dropdown in angular component while loading the form.

While loading the above form, I want to assign the city drop down value in angular component.

Any suggestions will help me.

```
<formio src="{{config.appUrl}}/esdtest"></formio>
```

I have accessed dropdown but am not able to set value :

```
ngAfterViewInit():void {  
  Formio.accessInfo().then(success => {
    var ddlcity = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementsByName("data[city]")[0];
    ddlcity.value="Hyderabad";
  })
}
```

`ddlcity.value="Hyderabad";` is not setting value to dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
ngAfterViewInit():void {
  Formio.accessInfo().then(success => {
    var ddlcity = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementsByName("data[city]")[0];
    for(let i=0; i<ddlcity.options.length; i++){
      if(ddlcity.options[i].value === 'Hyderabad'){
        ddlcity.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: HI gregoire, thanks for the response.
in the ngAfterViewInit my form is loading only dropdown its not loading all options.
can you suggest any event to set city value when all options are loaded